# First Isomorphism proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Theorem: First Isomorphism Theorem
>
> Let G and H be groups
>
> $\varphi :G\rightarrow H$ a Homomorphism
>
> Then, $G/\ker(\varphi) \cong \varphi(G)$ via the Isomorphism

$$\Psi:G/\ker(\varphi)\rightarrow \varphi(G)$$

$$(\ker(\varphi)) g \mapsto  (g)\varphi$$

The difficulty lies in showing that $\Psi$ is one-to-one.

To show that a map is one-to-one, we show that the only element that gets mapped to the identity is the identity itself.

> For ease of notation, let $K=\ker(\varphi)$

$$\ker(\Psi)=\left \{ Kg \in G/K \mid e=\varphi (g)\right \}$$
$$=\left \{ Kg \in G/K \mid g \in \ker(\varphi) \right\}
=K$$

Why is the defining property "$e=\varphi(g)$"?

Isn't the definition of $\ker(\Psi) \text{ really just } \ker(\Psi)= \left\{ Kg \in G/K \mid e=\Psi(Kg) \right\}?$

In the second line of the proof, how is $g \in \ker(\varphi)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you putting the function BEHIND things? it should be $\varphi(G)$

Comment: @ZelosMalum It is the same thing..

Comment: Not necciserily, it may mean many things if it comes behind that has nothing to do with homomorphisms and it's a very strange and peculiar notation. Better sticking to the norm.

Comment: My professor uses this convention..

Comment: @ZelosMalum Many group theorists write mappings on the right, so that composition is from left to right. It's annoying at first, but you get used to it after a while.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand this line in your post:
$(\ker(\varphi)) gx \mapsto x^2 (g)\varphi$

But you are spot on in defining $\Psi:G/\ker(\varphi)\rightarrow \varphi(G)$ and by this definition, $\Psi$ maps an element $Kg$ to some $\varphi(g)$. If this $Kg \in ker(\Psi)$ as well, it goes to $e$, and hence, we have: $\varphi(g) = e$. Hence $g \in ker (\varphi)$.

Comment: @Mathematicing: It seems there are plenty of posts on the First Isomorphism Theorem already. Have you looked at those? Some of them might help.

Comment: I've made the correction. Sorry for the blunder.

Comment: It slipped my mind to ask 'how' then is $Ker(\Psi)=K?$ Sure, by definition it is but how do I make the justification?
For this to be true, it must be that g=e.
The fact that $g \in Ker(\varphi)$ implies that g is some element that is mapped to the identity under $\varphi$ but does not necessarily implies that g=e.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the defining property "$e=\varphi(g)$"?
>
> Isn't the definition of $\ker(\Psi) \text{ really just } \ker(\Psi)= \left\{ Kg \in G/K \mid e=\Psi(Kg) \right\}?$

Yes, it is. And isn't by $\Psi$'s definition precisely $\Psi(Kg):=\varphi(g)$?

> In the second line of the proof, how is $g∈\ker(φ)$?

That's by the definition of $\ker(\varphi)$: $$g\in\ker\varphi\stackrel{(def.)}{\iff}\varphi(g)=e_H$$

From the comments:

> It slipped my mind to ask 'how' then is $\ker(Ψ)=K$?

That's because $g\in K\iff Kg=K$.

(Btw, note that the proof of $\Psi$'s injectivity is the "other direction" of the proof of $\Psi$'s good definition, which therefore should be firstly addressed.)